# Save the file containing the '/' or '\' or ':' in the name using std::ofstream

Tags: c++, file, stl

How can I save a file using `std::ofstream` with symbols such as `/` or `\\` or `:` in the name so that a folder is not created?

For example: `file/name.txt`.

Comment: `:` is a drive separator, and `/` and ```\``` are directory separators, they simply can't be used in a file name, period. Maybe ```\``` can be used on Linux, but certainly not on Windows.

Comment: You need to replace those chars with something else if your OS does not allow them. E.g. `"file%2Fname.txt"` (where `2F` is the ascii hex code of `/`) is one possible replacement.